# GtkScrolledWindow is mapped but visible child GtkScrollbar is not mapped

Tags: gtk

I trying to save and load a treeview from a text file

reeview with scroll windows container:

```
GtkWidget *scrolledwindow = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
gtk_scrolled_window_set_shadow_type(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(scrolledwindow), GTK_SHADOW_IN);
gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (scrolledwindow), GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC, GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC);

GtkListStore *store = gtk_list_store_new(2, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING);
GtkWidget *view = gtk_tree_view_new_with_model(GTK_TREE_MODEL(store));
gtk_tree_view_set_rules_hint (GTK_TREE_VIEW(view), TRUE);
gtk_tree_view_set_headers_visible(GTK_TREE_VIEW(view), FALSE);

selection = gtk_tree_view_get_selection(GTK_TREE_VIEW(view));
gtk_tree_selection_set_mode(selection, GTK_SELECTION_SINGLE);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrolledwindow), view);
```

Scenario:

In first case, treeview contains three rows with information entered in them. At this moment scrollbar isn't visible because treeview "request size" is for three row:

```
1. RED       100.00
-------------------
2. YELLOW    101.00
-------------------
3. BLUE      102.00
-------------------
```

I write a code to update, save and load a treeview from/to a text file  (I use "Load from file" button and "GTK_FILE_CHOOSER")

When import from this text file with contains more items (four, five, ...), list is updated with all new rows but get this warning:

```
GtkScrolledWindow 0x922f1e0 is mapped but visible child GtkScrollbar 0x93812b0 is not mapped


1. RED       100.00
-------------------
2. YELLOW    101.00
-------------------
3. BLUE      102.00
-------------------   
4. GREEN     103.00
-------------------
```

Same message is show up and when I export list to text file.

This message is show up after File chooser dialog is destroyed.

Also this happens when scrollbar is visible, file chosser dialog is up, I changed my mind and I choose to cancel action from "Cancel" button of  GTK_FILE_CHOOSER.

Thanks

Comment: You forgot the most interesting piece of code: the one you use to save/load from file. And the code you run you press cancel.